# How can I check a HTML dropdown against a dropdown stored in a Sharepoint 2013 list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, drop-down-menu

I currently have a static list of objects in the front end and a dropdown of objects sitting in a list. These are not actually list items. They are just possibilities on a dropdown on the list.

Front End:

```
<select>
<option value="co1">Country A</option>
<option value="co2">Country B</option>
<option value="co3">Country C</option>
<option value="co4">Country D</option>
<option value="co5">Country E</option>
<option value="co6">Country F</option>
</select>
```

JSON

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
            appweburl +
            "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?@High_Risk_Countries='" +
            hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    }
```

^^^ This is what I'm trying to do to solve the problem, but I'm aware it is not necessarily the correct way to go about it. My Problem is: I want to flag (with an alert or popup) if one of a group of values is chosen from the (currently static)dropdown. However this group is always changing so it needs to be dynamic.

I could probably replace the whole dropdown with a dynamic one from a list but unsure how to go about this completely.
Thanks,

Comment: I think it would be easier using JSOM (but that's my opinion) and just add the dropdown choices dynamically with javascript after the reading from the SP list is done (through promise)

Comment: Never used JSOM, I'll look into it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes like Verthosa say, you should use JSOM. And you should done this with the **JSLink** property of you field (the choice field).

With JSLink you can run function while your field is rendering client side. So you can simply add an event when seleting some option of you dropdown.
Check this link : [Client-side rendering (JS Link)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)